# How can use a match in the same regex in php?

Tags: php, regex, serialization

I have this string (that is a serialized variable in php):

```
s:12:"hello "world";
```

and I wanna to find "hello "world" only with regex, I try this, but seems it is stupid :P

```
(s:(?P<num>[0-9]+):".{\k{num}}";)
```

I only want to know how I can use "num" result in the its regex?

this regex is used in a big regex so I can't check for end of string.

thanks advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't... unserialize the string first? If it's part of a larger pattern you can grab the serialized bits and unserialize each of them.

Comment: I don't think you can. That would involve parsing the string into a number, which I don't think regex is capable of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your named capturing groups as backreference like this

> Back references to the named subpatterns can be achieved by (?P=name)
> or, since PHP 5.2.2, also by \k or \k'name'. Additionally PHP
> 5.2.4 added support for \k{name} and \g{name}.

[According to php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php)

But I think this can be used only to match the found pattern again, but not as a number in a quantifier. (At least I didn't got it to work.)

Comment: thank you! this is cool, but you right, in quantifier I can only use numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match` function, which will populate an array of matches:

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

More information about preg_match: [PHP: preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = 's:12:"hello "world";s:12:"good bue world";';
    $pattern = "(.*:[0-9]+:\"(.*)\";.*)U";
    preg_match_all($pattern,$text,$r);
```

Comment: my problem is I don't know what string maybe in this string, "hello "world" is only a sample

Comment: this is nice, but you know serialized php variables can contain anything even "; like this: s:13:"hello ";world";

Comment: so, can you give me full sample with all possible cases?

Comment: some thing like this: s:12:"hello ";'world";s:12:"good bue world";